# Probability of a random number in [0,1] having a k-digit sequence infinitely many times

Tags: probability-theory

The problem states: Given a uniformly random number $X\in [0,1]$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and a k-length sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\in \lbrace0,\ldots,9\rbrace^k$. What is the probability of the sequence appearing infinitely many times in the decimal expansion of X.

I know that if $A_n = \lbrace\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)_{n+j-1} = a_j\quad \forall j\in\lbrace1,\ldots,k \rbrace\rbrace$.
Then $P(A_n) = (\frac{1}{10})^k$.
And I would then be interested in the event $\cap_{j=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n\geq j}^{\infty} A_n$.
I would be tempted to use Borel-Cantelli's theorem to prove its either 0 or 1, yet the $A_n$ are not independent since, if they are consecutive and k is greater than 1, it fails and $\sum_n P(A_n)$ diverges, so I can't use it. My intuition tells me it should be something like $\frac{1}{10^k}$ or 0, but I'm not really sure anyway

Comment: Just instead of looking at $A_n$ for every $n$, take a look at subsequence $A_{kn + 1}$ for example, so that those are independent

Comment: "A random number $X \in [0,1]$" is not very precise.  I assume $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $P[X=0]=P[X=1]=1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is $1$. We can simulate a draw from $\operatorname{Unif}[0,1)$ by drawing an infinite sequence of i.i.d. $X_i \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUnif}\{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$ and then letting $X = 0.X_1X_2X_3\ldots$. From here, it's immediate that any finite sequence will occur an infinite number of times with probability $1$.

---

To justify the above claim, let $Y_n = (X_{kn+1}, \ldots, X_{kn})$, and let $E_n$ denote the event that $Y_n = (a_1, \ldots, a_k)$. Clearly $P(E_n) = \frac{1}{10^k}$, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(E_n) = \infty$.
\begin{align}&P(\text{the sequence } (a_1, \ldots, a_k)\text{ occurs infinitely many times}) \\
\geq &P(\text{an infinite number of }E_i\text{ occur})\\
=&1
 \end{align}
by the second [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) since  and each $E_i$ are independent.